# Use cases of REST

Tags: http, web-applications, rest, saas

Is REST even designed to be used by a SaaS? Are there any examples of this? What's all the jazz about it whilst it's not even being used widely

Yes, REST is there for machines to communicate with each other and bla bla and bla.
What's the use of it is no user-centric real-life software uses it where user commands the machine to communicate with another machine?

If this is the case, in which REST is there for APIs and SOLELY and ONLY web-services, what's all the jazz about it?

Comment: It might help to re-word your question to make it a bit more clear. As it stands, it's difficult to tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closer at **the site in which you have just placed your question**, you may notice it uses REST actively.

I am not sure whether I understand your question properly *(it may be that either my, or your English is insufficient)*, but if you look at the modern sites, you may notice that in most of them the user interacts with JavaScript *(one machine)*, which interacts with the server *(another machine)*.

I guess that REST is considered so good idea, because it is simple to define, simple to implement, and once you get used to it, you can interact with any service in similar manner.

If your question is about something different, accept my apologies.

Comment: Sites do use GET and POST. Which sites do use PUT and DELETE? Bar the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

At first: REST and WebServices are not quite the same things, although they're mostly (ab)used synonymously.

REST was designed to interchange pure data between 2 machines, while WebServices provide a whole service. So, answering your topic (which doesn't quite seem to to match your explaination for me...): No, REST was not designed to be used by SaaS or as a WebService, but it's easily possible.

> "[...]no user-centric real-life software uses it[...]"

Are you saying, that data interchange between 2 machines is not being used in real-life software? Even opening a page in your browser contains a lot of communication of that kind. Or you eMail-client checking for emails once in a while.

REST and WebServices simply provide standardized interfaces for requesting a service or data/information from another machine.

I must confess, your formulation of the question is not quite clear to me, so I hope my answer covers it in some way.